# HTTP statuscode error for AuthorizationFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-authorization

I've created an custom AuthorizationFilterAttribute below for my WebAPI 2 app:

```
public class ApiKeyRequiredAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    private string key;

    public ApiKeyRequiredAttribute(string key) : base()
    {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> headers = new List<string>();
        actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("x-apikey", out headers);
        if (!headers.Any() || headers.Single() != this.key)
        {
            throw new SecurityException("Invalid API key provided");
        }
        return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

It does what it's supposed to do: users with the correct header see the results, others get an exception. However - how can I return an `HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized`?

As soon as I don't throw an exception - the normal execution flow continues. Surely I don't have to implement a global exception handler, right?

Answer (score 0):

Without testing this, you can create an ErrorResponse from the current request like this :-

```
public class ApiKeyRequiredAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        private string key;

        public ApiKeyRequiredAttribute(string key)
            : base()
        {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> headers = new List<string>();
            actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("x-apikey", out headers);
            if (!headers.Any() || headers.Single() != this.key)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
                    new SecurityException("Invalid API key Provided"));
            }
            return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - but that doesn't work. That will not block the controller method execution.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the Async variant?